# Remove old slider and remove Selected/Featured products from home page Nopcommerce Ver-3.90 (Prisma Theme)

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90, nopcommerce-themes

Im currently trying to configure our new web store since we updated from Ver-3.30 to 3.90 and we are using the Prisma Theme and a different folder for the new version of our shop. The problem is i cannot find the slider on the top of the page to remove it and replace it with the Nivo slider and i would like also to remove the Selected Products under it so i can add my own using the SmartProducts - Jcarousel Plugins. Ive checked all my files under the View Folder and tried commenting out some stuff that i read through the forums but nothing happens not even an error. Thank you in advance.

Zac

https://ninos-sports.com/eshop/    <---This is the website in case you would like to have a look!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is i cannot find the slider on the top of the page to remove it and replace it with the Nivo slider

If you want remove/update any image from slider than you can visit nivo slider plugin configuration page and mange slider image from that.
Look at here in admin demo: http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/Admin/WidgetsNivoSlider/Configure

for this navigate to Admin > Configuration > Widgets > click on configure button of nivo slider row

If you want to complete remove slider, **than you need to disable widget**
for this navigate to Admin > Configuration > Widgets

Click on Edit button of Nivo slider and uncheck in Is Active column

> i would like also to remove the Selected Products under it

For remove products under nivo slider, go to product edit page in Admin panel and uncheck to **Show on home page**

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your site.

I think you used anywhere slider.

If you want to remove than you should disable anywhere slider widget.

Go through => Admin > Configuration > Widgets > click on configure button of anywhere slider.

After if you have to replace with nivo slider than active that one.

Furthermore.

If you have to remove home page product than you have to disable show on home page checkbox from admin => catalog > products => edit